# Profit and loss problem

Tags: percentages

A shopkeeper allows a discount of 12.5% on the marked price of a certain article and makes a profit of 20%. If the article costs the shopkeeper Rs 210,  then the marked price of the article will be?

Comment: So the discounted price is $(1-\tfrac{12.5}{100})$ times the marked price, and the discounted price is $(1+\tfrac{20}{100})$ times the cost of $\mathcal{Rs}210$. Then the marked price is equal to *what* times the cost?

Comment: Yes what times the cost

Comment: Hint: divide and calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given that :
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{discounted} &= (100\%-12.5\%)\times\operatorname{marked}
\\[1ex]
\operatorname{discounted}&=(100\%+20\%)\times\operatorname{cost}
\\[1ex]
\operatorname{cost} &= \mathcal {Rs}\;120
\end{align}$$

Then clearly:

$$(100\%-12.5\%)\times\operatorname{marked}=(100\%+20\%)\times\mathcal {Rs}\;120$$

So it follows that:
$$\therefore \operatorname{marked} = \dfrac{\Box}{\Box}$$

Answer (score 0):

At 20% profit, the selling price is 210*120/100=Rs252/-

Let, Marked Price is Rs100
At 12.5% discount the selling price is (100-12.5)=87.5Rs
If selling price is Rs87.5 then the marked price is Rs100

Now if selling price is Rs87.5 then the marked price is Rs100
    if selling price is Rs252 then the marked price is Rs100*252/87.5=Rs288
So The marked Price is Rs288